# Convert index/match to vba from separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I'm trying to set up a variable index match from another sheet and have tried every solution on here so maybe I'm just messing it up.

I have 2 sheets:  "Job 1", and "Jobs"

Job 1:    E3 = job type, AKA the table names.
H3 is the title lookup (from column 1 of each table)
L3 is where I want the result (The job number that matches the title from H3

[Pic of Job 1 sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWsuq.png)

Jobs:     15 tables, each 4 columns wide, varying and changing lengths.  Headers in row 2, data
starts in row 3  .   First table (FRM 5) starts at column AP

[image]

"Job 1" is where the lookup reference is, and "Jobs" is where all the data is.  There are 15 possible (IF) contingencies, and matching tables on the "Jobs" sheet.  The tables are dynamic and change data on their own if that matters?

The tables on the "Jobs" sheet are:

FRM5,
FRM6,
CM,
FRM4,
LCM,
ULCM,
CRU,
LP,
URER,
Rebuild,
LM,
EVAL,
CON,
EPC,
FOR

I have this formula that works, but I need to move it to VBA:

```txt
=IF(E3="FRM5",INDEX(Jobs!AQ3:AQ200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!AP3:AP200,0)),
IF(E3="FRM6",INDEX(Jobs!AV3:AV200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!AU3:AU200,0)),
IF(E3="CM",INDEX(Jobs!BA3:BA200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!AZ3:AZ200,0)),
IF(E3="FRM4",INDEX(Jobs!BF3:BF200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!BE3:BE200,0)),
IF(E3="LCM",INDEX(Jobs!BK3:BK200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!BJ3:BJ200,0)),
IF(E3="ULCM",INDEX(Jobs!BP3:BP200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!BO3:BO200,0)),
IF(E3="CRU",INDEX(Jobs!BU3:BU200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!BT3:BT200,0)),
IF(E3="LP",INDEX(Jobs!BZ3:BZ200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!BY3:BY200,0)),
IF(E3="URER",INDEX(Jobs!CE3:CE200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!CD3:CD200,0)),
IF(E3="Rebuild",INDEX(Jobs!CJ3:CJ200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!CI3:CI200,0)),
IF(E3="LM",INDEX(Jobs!CO3:CO200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!CN3:CN200,0)),
IF(E3="Eval",INDEX(Jobs!CT3:CT200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!CS3:CS200,0)),
IF(E3="CON",INDEX(Jobs!CY3:CY200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!CX3:CX200,0)),
IF(E3="EPC",INDEX(Jobs!DD3:DD200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!DC3:DC200,0)),
IF(E3="FOR",INDEX(Jobs!DI3:DI200,MATCH('Job 1'!H3,Jobs!DH3:DH200,0)
))))))))))))))))
```

I need to reference the table columns, rather than just ranges, because the lists keep going over the 200 threshold and missing stuff.

All the tables have the exact same column headers:  Title, Job #, WO # Tier

I am trying to pull the Job # based off the Title

Ive tried many different variations, but this is what I currently have:

```
Dim Jobs As Worksheet
Set Jobs = Worksheets("Jobs")
Dim Job1 As Worksheet
Set Job1 = Worksheets("Job 1")

If Job1.Range("E3").Value = "FRM 5" Then

Job1.Range("L3").Value = worksheetfuncion.Index(Jobs.Range("AQ3:AQ200"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Job1.Range("E3").Value, _
Jobs.Range("Ap3:Ap200"), 0))

End If
```

I'm using MS 365 if that matters.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The code only shows the first "IF", I was going to copy/paste for each of the 15 table names and just change the name in the "IF" statement?

Answer (score 0):

Write a User-Defined Function which takes the table name and the value to be looked up - use `Match` to locate the table name in Row1 on "Jobs", then offset from there to do the lookup.

Put this in a regular module:

```vb
Function JobNumber(TableName As String, Title As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, m, rng As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jobs")
    m = Application.Match(TableName, ws.Rows(1), 0) 'try to match the table header
    If Not IsError(m) Then                          'table matched?
        'get the match range
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, m).Offset(2), _
                           ws.Cells(Rows.Count, m).End(xlUp))
        m = Application.Match(Title, rng, 0)               'try to match the title
        If Not IsError(m) Then                             'title matched?
            JobNumber = rng.Cells(m).Offset(0, 1).Value   'offset for the Job#
        Else
            JobNumber = "?Title?"
        End If
    Else
        JobNumber = "?Table?"
    End If
End Function
```

Example usage:

[image]

Comment: Is this to be pasted on the ("Jobs") code sheet, or the ("Job 1") code sheet?  When I paste to the Job 1 code the whole sheets code stops running.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It would go in a regular code module and be called like `=JobNumber(E3, H3)`